# Changing the font in immunity debugger?

Tags: immunity-debugger

Does anyone know how to change the font size in immunity debugger? The font option under Options -> Appearance -> Font doesn't seem to change anything and just resets whenever you restart the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to figure out the problem I came with the following solution:

- Open Immunity Debugger as an Administrator
- Go to `Options >> Appearance >> Fonts`
- Rename one of the fonts to whatever name you'd like
- Click on `Change` and set the settings you wish
- Go to `Defaults` tab and set the `Default font` to be the one you edited.
- Done.

Now the configuration stays any time you open Immunity as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

- after loading a program the panes are filled with data
- right-click in the top left pane and a menu will appear
- from this menu choose appearence --> font(all) --> the font you want (the "OEM fixed font" works for me)